# Daemon is launching under user after OS X reboot

Tags: macos, permissions, root, daemon, launchd

I've developed daemon which is running as daemon under root user (I see it in activity monitor). After Mac OS X reboot it running as my user "jsmith" (NOT as root)

I set launchctl plist chown to root before reboot by:

> sudo chown root com.daemon.mydaemon.plist

Please note that user id is the same as root.(equal to "0") I checked it by:

> id -u jsmith

How to keep displaying username as "root" in Activity Monitor?

Comment: Having two users with the same id is wrong, especially if its id is zero. I suggest changing that by deleting the user and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

The user under which a daemon runs is controlled by a keyed value in the daemon's configuration property list (plist).

In order for a daemon to run as root, the plist must describe the UserName, like this:-

```
<Key>UserName</Key>
<string>root</string>
```

This is mentioned in the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-104489).